# Auto update div content inside slider jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I get my div content inside slider jquery auto update when MySQL has changed or has a new row added?

I've tried with my code, But my slider doesn't work and can't slide any div content.

**My code :**

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-theme.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.single-item').slick({
                dots: false,
                infinite: true,
                speed: 700,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                $('.single-item').load('item.php');
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: darkturquoise;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="single-item" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: auto;">

</div>

</html>
```

**item.php**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fm_product WHERE p_pined = 'PINED'") or die(mysql_error());
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo '<div style="background-color: white; height: 200px;">'.$result['p_id'].'</div>';
}

?>
```

My code given output:

[image: output]

Comment: you mean when MYSQL row changes in backgroud , without page refresh you want to change the slider contents ?

Comment: @n01ze Yes, When MySQL has changed or has updated my DIV content inside slider jQuery will auto update like: If my div content has A,B,C rows when I add D row into mysql, My div content in slider jQuery will have A,B,C and D. But my slider jQuery code it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this qualifies as a complete answer, but a main problem lies in your usage of `.load` and it's interaction (or lack thereof) with the slick slider plugin.

The order of events on your page is as follows:

1. The dom is loaded & ready.
2. Slick Slider is initialised on `.single-item`. The contents of `.single-item` (currently nothing) is replaced with slick slider's HTML to set up and render the slides, control buttons etc. properly.

   - This is important because `.single-item` is now full of a lot of different HTML elements. If you're unsure what it looks like, [check the slick slider demo page](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) - view the page source, then view the source using developer tools to see the change in how it looks.
   - Additionally, `.single-item` never had any content originally, so it will render zero slides. At this point, you've created an empty slider.
3. Your `setInterval` event is registered.
4. 3 seconds pass.
5. Your `setInterval` event fires for the first time. An [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is made to `item.php`, which responds with HTML - a bunch of styled `divs` containing data.

   - At this point, you can use your developer tools to confirm that `item.php` is returning the correct data by monitoring your network requests area.
6. Your script takes the request response (the HTML) and **completely replaces `single-item`'s contents with it.**

   - Alarm bells should be ringing at this point, as this immediately causes a conflict between what used to be in this element (slick's HTML setup) and what it has replaced. If you look in your developer tools console, you might even spot some errors popping up from slick complaining about missing elements.
7. `GOTO STEP4`

What's happening is that your `.load` call is replacing the contents of an element containing a slick slider setup, totally breaking the slider.

What you need to do is change how you handle the AJAX. You should drop the `.load` and move towards using `$.ajax` for nicer callback control. Based on the [slick docs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) you can either:

- On each XHR request return - destroy the slick slider with `$('.single-item').slick('unslick');`, insert the contents into `.single-item`, then re-initialize the slider.
- Keep track of the current slides. On each XHR return, detect which slides are present and which ones aren't, and remove/add them to the slider using `.slick('slickAdd', HtmlOrDomNode`) and `.slick('slickRemove' slideIndex)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you forget 1 thing : On XHR request check if data result has changed : if not, no need to reload. (edit : my bad, I missread your last point about `Keep Tracking` or you edit it.)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I can solved my problem now. :)